# Required property on a field doesn't change dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

One of my fields should be either mandatory(required) or not depending on one boolean variable. No matter if it changes or not the field stays required. Not sure what's wrong with my `expressionProperties templateOptions.required` as this is what triggers that change.

This is part of my formly form

```
vm.showDeleteButton = false;

vm.fields = [
    {
        className: 'row',
        fieldGroup: [
            {
                className: 'col-xs-6',
                key: 'transferDate',
                type: 'datepicker',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Deallocation Date',
                    type: 'text',
                    datepickerPopup: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    minDate: vm.model.minDate,
                    maxDate: vm.model.maxdate,
                },
                expressionProperties: {
                    'templateOptions.required': !vm.showDeleteButton
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Also tried this

```
expressionProperties: {
    'templateOptions.required': function() {
         if(!vm.showDeleteButton) {
              return true;
         else {
              return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

I've read the formly expressions documentation but that doesn't help either.

HTML as requested

```
<formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options" form="vm.form"></formly-form>
```

Comment: Can you please attach the HTML template?

Comment: It's formly form, most of the form config is defined in vm.fields but I've updated the post with HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Kind of 'hacked' it to work.

Changed `vm.showDeleteButton` to `vm.model.showDeleteButton` and in my `expressionProperties` wrote this

```
expressionProperties: {
   'templateOptions.required': '!model.showDeleteButton'
}
```

Comment: If you've got a better solution, please let me know.